# LinkedIn Follow plugin.. how to create? How to call OADataFetcher and How to handle callback methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linkedin-api

LinkedIn Follow plugin.. how to create? how to call `OADataFetcher` and How to handle callback methods? These are the major tasks in `LinkedIn`..

Please tell me the reply..please soon.